# multiproject sbt doesn't generate file structure

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to sbt (using sbt.version=0.13.5) created multiproject build definition as following (build.sbt):

```
name := "hello-app"

version in ThisBuild := "1.0.0"

organization in ThisBuild := "com.jaksky.hello"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

ideaExcludeFolders ++= Seq (
    ".idea",
    ".idea_modules"
)

lazy val common = (
  Project("common",file("common"))
)

lazy val be_services = (
  Project("be-services",file("be-services"))
  dependsOn(common)
)
```

My expectation was that sbt will generate directory layout for the projects (based on the documentation). What happened was that just only top directories were generated (common and be-services) with target folder in it.

I tried it in batch mode sbt compile or in interactive mode - none has generated expected folder structures e.g. /src/{main, test}/{scala, java, resources}.

So either my expectations are wrong or there is some problem in my definition or some speciall setting, plugin etc.

Could some more experienced user clarify that, please?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen sbt generating project folders. Do you have a link to the page of the documentation where it is indicated?

Comment: I found that in book SBT in action as one of the features or highlights

Comment: I haven't read this book yet :) Haven't found anything like that in sbt doc. Not even in sbt-extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vptheron correctly points out, sbt does not generate any project directories, with the exception of the `target` directory when it produces compiled class files.

You might find that functionality in plugins, e.g. [np](https://github.com/softprops/np). Also if you use an IDE such as IntelliJ IDEA, creating a new sbt-based project will initialize a couple of directories (such as `src`).